# Voronoi Polygon Coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon, matlab, voronoi-thiessen, mmqgis

I am using Voronoi polygon coordinates and respective node coordinates together. To apply the load to that particular node which is obtained by summing up the loads that lies within the polygon. By exporting geometry property I am getting nodal and polygon coordinates in separate files. Can I able to get those files together? Or else the polygon coordinates for one shape id within one row?

[[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. You have a (point?) layer from which you have generated voronoi polygons. I am assuming you must also have another (point?) layer and you wish to sum attributes ("load"?) of this layer, by polygons in the voronoi polygon layer. Is this correct? Also, it is not possible to answer the question without knowing the software that are you using.

Comment: Reading again another interpretation might be that you have generated Voronoi polygons, extracted the nodes of this layer and now wish to sum an attribute ("load"?) of these nodes, by voronoi polygon. In which case, each node will belong to more than one polygon. Where did the attribute "load" come from?

Comment: I have several nodes. For example 50 nodes. For each nodes i have drawn voronoi polygon. from MMQGIS > the geometry export option, the shape id and respective polygon coordinates are exported to CSV file as attached in image 2.I am using matlab coding to get the final result.In that I need to get the coordinates for each point in the following attachment 1. Is that possible to get in this order

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question. If not, please add some more detail so we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the polygons have an id attribute.
Then vector -> Geometry Tools --> Extract Nodes. This will give you a point file with the attributes of the source polygons for each node. Then save the layer as a CSV. This will give a table with the attributes (including your id) and x, y values.